# SQL query Group records by given Date Range

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a table which have some field there is a checkup_date field(type=datetime, ex: value= '2013-11-13 14:20:30'). I write a query group by year

```
SELECT year(eh_patient_checkup.checkup_date) as 'Year', count(*)
  FROM phcdb.eh_patient_checkup eh_patient_checkup
GROUP BY year(eh_patient_checkup.checkup_date)
```

it show me result like

```
Year ----- count(*)
-----------------
2011 ----- 203
2012 ----- 1007
2013 ----- 3020
```

But I want it to GROUP BY every April 1 to March 31(next year). For example

```
Year ------------------------- count(*)
--------------------------------------
2011-04-01 to 2012-03-31 ----- 203
2012-04-01 to 2013-03-31 ----- 5656
2013-04-01 to 2014-03-31 ----- 1213
```

Can anyone help me for improving my query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `datediff`

```
SELECT date_add('2013-04-01', INTERVAL YearDiff YEAR) 'from date'
, date_add('2013-04-01', INTERVAL YearDiff + 1 YEAR) 'to date'
, Amount
FROM
(
    SELECT floor(datediff(eh_patient_checkup.checkup_date,'2013-04-01') / 365) as 'YearDiff', count(*) AS 'Amount'
    FROM phcdb.eh_patient_checkup eh_patient_checkup
    GROUP BY floor(datediff(eh_patient_checkup.checkup_date,'2013-04-01') / 365)
) as temp
```

The only work to do is that you have to get the correct year-range in the select.

Comment: MySQL Database Error: Incorrect parameter count in the call to native function 'datediff'

Comment: May be because of the double quotes in the date. I have removed it.

Comment: Sorry, I already saw, that you use mysql, my query is for mssql. I will change it

Comment: yea, thats the year-diff. Now we have to apply the date_add function.

Comment: MySQL Database Error: Every derived table must have its own alias